# メソッドのラベル（外部名）の使用について

Tags: swift

[Swift言語を学ぶ](http://tea-leaves.jp/swift/content/%E3%82%B5%E3%83%96%E3%82%B9%E3%82%AF%E3%83%AA%E3%83%97%E3%83%88)

上記サイトの最後のコードが以下になります。

```
/* オセロのコマ */
enum Piece {
    case Black, White
}

/* オセロ盤 */
class OthelloBoard {
    class var rows: Int    { return 8 }
    class var columns: Int { return 8 }
    class var squares: Int { return rows * columns }
    var board: [Piece?]
    init() {
        board = Array(count: OthelloBoard.squares, repeatedValue: nil)
        self[3, 3] = .Black;  self[3, 4] = .White
        self[4, 3] = .White; self[4, 4] = .Black
    }
    // 指定されたマス目のコマを返す
    subscript(row: Int, column: Int) -> Piece? {
        get {
            checkSquare(row, column: column)
            return board[row * OthelloBoard.columns + column]
        }
        set {
            checkSquare(row, column: column)
            board[row * OthelloBoard.columns + column] = newValue
        }
    }
    // 位置の検証
    func checkSquare(row: Int, column: Int) {
        assert(row < OthelloBoard.rows && column < OthelloBoard.columns, "不正な位置")
    }
}

let board = OthelloBoard()
board[3, 5] = .Black
```

このコードの、subscriptのgetとsetの中でcheckSquareメソッドを実行していますが、なぜcolumnにラベル（外部名）が付いているのでしょうか？

checkSquareの定義のところでは、引数名だけでラベルは定義されていません。

しかし、getとsetの中でcheckSquareメソッドの、rowにラベルを付けたり、columnのラベルを外すとエラーがでます。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: リンク先の前ページ（「メソッド」）に、そのものずばりの説明があります。それをお読みになった上でのご質問だと思うのですが、どのような解決していない疑問が残っているのでしょうか？

Comment: メソッドの項目を読んでませんでした。失礼致しました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift は新しい言語ですが、OS X / iOS プラットフォームでこれまで使われていた Objective-C からの移行をしやすくするための仕様も含まれています。

メソッドの構文は関数の構文と同じなのですが、第一引数の外部名はデフォルトでは付けることができず、第二引数の外部名には、暗黙的に内部名が使われます。

これには、Swift のメソッド名に当たる部分に第一引数のラベル部分が含まれ、第二引数以降のラベルを（普通は）省略しない、という Objective-C のメソッド名の特徴が引き継がれています。

挙げていただいたウェブサイトにも詳しく書かれているようですので、参考にしてみてください：
[メソッド | Swift言語を学ぶ](http://tea-leaves.jp/swift/content/%E3%83%A1%E3%82%BD%E3%83%83%E3%83%89)

Comment: ご説明頂いた内容と、メソッドの項目を読み、理解できました。
ありがとうございました。